# Where should I find [sp_xml_preparedocument]?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I recently used [sp_xml_preparedocument] to parse an XML file to analyze the parameter data.

What is interesting to me is that when I drill into my SQLServer 2k8r2 instance I cannot seem to actually find a procedure named [sp_xml_preparedocument].

I've been looking in System Databases/Mater and the Db I created for the analysis and it does not appear.

However [EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x] executes just fine.

I'd like to deepen my understanding of what is occurring and review the actual procedure.

Where should this stored procedure actually appear?

Comment: Just as a hint: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`sp_xml_preparedocument` is a system extended stored procedure. From SSMS Object Explorer, you'll find it under Databases-->System Databases-->Programmability-->System Extended Stored Procedures.

Since it's an unmanaged extended proc written in C++, not T-SQL, so you won't be able to review the source code. It used to just wrap the msxml COM API but I'm not sure if that's still the case nowadays since it's internal SQL Server code.

Comment: Thanks Dan!  Question:  My instance does not have a Programmability node in System Databases.  I see that directory as part of the individual System Databases but do not see System EXTENDED Stored Procedures.   I do see System Stored Procedures, but no sp_xml_preparedocument.  I think I'm interpreting your notes to mean this may be hidden from the explorer view.  Is that right?

Comment: @LearnsWhileDoing, it might depend what version of SSMS you are using. I see it using the latest version of SSMS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), which is a free download.